# Use MSBuild to generate CHM file with RoboHelp HTML X5

Tags: msbuild, robohelp

We use RoboHelp HTML X5.x.x to generate CHM files for our help system. Is it possible to run RoboHelp unattended, non-UI, like from a command-line, so it can be integrated with our MSBuild build process?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RoboHelp) that command-line compilation appears in version 6 of RoboHelp so I don't think you can with your version.

Comment: Sounds like all the reason I would need to upgrade or switch to another tool.  Not including all aspects of the product in the CI system in unacceptable in my book.